Get year from report timestamp
I'm trying to get the year out of a report timestamp using tbe helow
var year = reportTimestamp.getFullYear();

I keep getting this error:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getFullYear')

Tried .getYear as well with no luck

The obvious answer is that reportTimestamp is undefined whereas you expect it to be a Date. Fix that and you might get somewhere.

I'm no expert but the problem seems to be in the definition of the variable reportTimestamp and not in the line var year = reportTimestamp.getFullYear();
Maybe share what you are doing to define the varible reportTimestamp so someone can see what the problem is.
For example this function works:
function myFunction() {
  var reportTimestamp = new Date(); 
  var year = reportTimestamp.getFullYear();
  console.log(year);
}


function createReport(holdID,reportTimestamp) {
var ss= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //active google sheet
var reportTemplate = ss.getSheetByName("Hold Report Template").getRange("A:M");  //hold report template
var values = reportTemplate.getValues();
var bGcolors = reportTemplate.getBackgrounds();
var colors = reportTemplate.getFontColors();
var style = reportTemplate.getTextStyles();
var year = reportTimestamp.getFullYear();

No @AlexBigus, that is a function that asks for the reportTimestamp value, id does not define it. When you call that function you have to put a variable o something in there. How do you define that variable or what value are you puting there when you call the function?

@AlexBigus—don't put additional information in comments, add it to the question using the edit function.
